# How do find $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u \, \partial v}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

have a problem solving this problem, since I find it difficult to find the derivatives of $z$ with respect to $u$ and $v$, I would appreciate any help you can give me.

$$
z= f\left(xy,\ \frac y x \right)
$$
Where x and y belong to $\Bbb R$
And $$xy=u$$ $$\frac{y}{x}=v$$
 How do find

$$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u \, \partial v} $$

Comment: Chain rule, no ?

Answer (score 2):

I think f(u,v) can also be thought as f(x,y) via $uv=y^2$ and $\frac{u}{v}=x^2$. Then to take $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}$$ This should be equal to 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (\frac{-u^\frac{1}{2}}{2v^\frac{3}{2}}) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (\frac{u^\frac{1}{2}}{2v^\frac{1}{2}})$$
The second derivative should look like 
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u \partial v}=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (\frac{-u^\frac{1}{2}}{2v^\frac{3}{2}}) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (\frac{u^\frac{1}{2}}{2v^\frac{1}{2}})\right)\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left((\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (\frac{-u^\frac{1}{2}}{2v^\frac{3}{2}}) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (\frac{u^\frac{1}{2}}{2v^\frac{1}{2}})\right)\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}.$$
At the end you should be able to rewrite everything in terms of x, y, $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}$, $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}$, $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}$. Hopefully this hint helps.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I think that to apply the second derivatives, it helps to write all the u's and v's inside the big parenthesis in terms of x and y and then simplify and derivate.

Comment: Actually you might want to refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2245774/z-f-leftxy-frac-y-x-right-differentiate?rq=1 
The same question is posted and seems answered already. :)